# Clear the Text box data in the magento 2 module when validation fails in beforeSave event

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module

I have a textbox which gets a input from the User. I have created a validation point using beforeSave function. If the validation fails, An error displays. Along with this I want to delete the value from the textbox. How to achieve this?